# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'BookReservationRQReservation[]

Tags: c#, arraylist, types

I have an ArrayList i want to add items inside it then assign it with `bookingrquest.Reservations` i tried several times but i did not get solution for it, how to convert ArrayList to  BookReservationRQReservation[]

```
 BookReservationRQ bookingrquest = new BookReservationRQ();
  ArrayList reservation = new ArrayList();

  int count = 0;

  foreach (var item in reservation_details.selectedrooms)
  {
      reservation.Add(item.IDHotel);
      count++;
  }


  bookingrquest.Reservations = reservation;// i have this error in this line


   public BookReservationRQReservation[] Reservations {
     get {
        return this.reservationsField;
     }
     set {
         this.reservationsField = value;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Well, it seems you defined `bookingrquest.Reservations` as an _array_ of `BookReservationRQReservation`, and that is not the same as an _arraylist_ containing `IDHotel` items. How about you try to create an array of  `BookReservationRQReservation`?

Comment: What type is `IDHotel` of? Is this an `BookReservationRQReservation` at all?

Comment: @RenéVogt IDHotel is stirng this is not he problem the problem is on the `bookingrquest.Reservations = reservation;`

Comment: Of course it is (part of) the problem. You cannot put `string`s into an array of `BookReservationRQReservation`s. How do you create a `BookReservationRQReservation` out of a `string`?

Comment: @RenéVogt i updated the question with `BookReservationRQReservation `

Comment: But that's not the point. You have a list of **`string`**, but want to have `BookReservationRQReservation` instead. Is there any conversion from `string` to `BookReservationRQReservation` or does `BookReservationRQReservation` declare a constructor that takes a `string`?

Answer (score -1):

Since your request object needs an array, How about uzing arrays directly by replacing:

```
ArrayList reservation = new ArrayList();
```

With

```
BookReservationRQReservation reservation = new BookReservationRQReservation[reservation_details.selectedrooms.Length];
```

assuming that reservation_details.selected is a List

and then replace

```
 reservation.Add(item.IDHotel);
```

With

```
reservation[iter++] = item.IDHotel;
```

Before for loop, do initialize iter=0

Comment: This won't compile unless there is an implicit conversion from `string` to `BookReservationRQReservation`. OP said `IDHotel` is of type `string`, not `BookReservationRQReservation`.

Comment: @RenéVogt, At the time of answer, that comment was not available. Secondly, before upvoting or down voting, I try to get the intention. If it is of String type then last replaced statement can be enhanced accordingly

Comment: I know, thatswhy I asked OP to clarify instead of guessing the most important information of this problem.